# How to label a grouped by pandas boxplot?

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I have a dataframe that I want to boxplot using groupby, The x-axis is labeled but the y-axis is not. How do I label the y-axis?

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(12,2), columns=['Apples', 'Oranges'] )
df['Categories'] = pd.Series(list('AAAABBBBCCCC'))
df.boxplot(by='Categories')
plt.ylabel("LABELLL")
```

I'd like the label 'LABELL' to be part of the plot, on the y axis. How do I do that?
[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

```py
ax = df.boxplot(by='Categories')
ax[0].set_ylabel("LABELLL")
```

[`df.boxplot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html) returns a `numpy.ndarray` of `matplotlib.axes.Axes` objects. You can then [set the ylabel](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylabel.html) on the first one.